# Complex SQL issue in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK` which contains `USER_ID` and `BOOK_CODE`. This table shows which all books are with a particular USER_ID.

```
USER_ID         BOOK_CODE
------------------------------
1               123
1               124
1               567
2               123
2               432
3               432
3               567
-------------------------------
```

I have another table `TABLE_BOOK` which contains details about each book.

```
BOOK_CODE        DETAILS
----------------------------------
123              abcd
124              pqrs 
432              xyzw
567              lmnop
568              efgh
----------------------------------
```

I want to write a query between the two tables which will spit out `USER_ID` and `BOOK_CODE` where BOOK_CODE column should have the id of all books from `TABLE_BOOK` which that user doesn't have. For e.g. user 1 doesn't have books 432 and 568, user 2 doesn't have 124, 567 and 568 and user 3 doesn't have 123, 124, 568.

So the result table of the query would be:

```
USER_ID     BOOK_CODE
----------------------------
1           432
1           568
2           124
2           567
2           568
3           123
3           124
3           568
-----------------------------
```

This report is to advertise the books which user doesn't have.

How do I achieve this in SQL in DB2 9 ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Homework? What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: @jarlh: I am too old for homework :) Mental block

Comment: I think left join can work for you.

Comment: Vicky.  Did this work for you w/o a Group By?  Txs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `CROSS JOIN` to get all user/book combinations. Use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude already existing combinations:

```
select distinct tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE
from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK tcb
    cross join TABLE_BOOK tb
where not exists (select * from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK tcb2
                  where tcb2.USER_ID = tcb.USER_ID
                    and tcb2.BOOK_CODE = tb.BOOK_CODE)
order by tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE
```

Alternatively, `EXCEPT`:

```
select tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE
from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK tcb
    cross join TABLE_BOOK tb
EXCEPT
select USER_ID, BOOK_CODE
from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK
order by tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE
```

No `DISTINCT` needed here. `EXCEPT` removes the duplicates.

Executes as:

```
SQL>select distinct tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE
SQL&from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK tcb
SQL&    cross join TABLE_BOOK tb
SQL&where not exists (select * from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK tcb2
SQL&                  where tcb2.USER_ID = tcb.USER_ID
SQL&                    and tcb2.BOOK_CODE = tb.BOOK_CODE)
SQL&order by tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE;
    USER_ID   BOOK_CODE
=========== ===========
          1         432
          1         568
          2         124
          2         567
          2         568
          3         123
          3         124
          3         568

                  8 rows found

SQL>select tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE
SQL&from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK tcb
SQL&    cross join TABLE_BOOK tb
SQL&EXCEPT
SQL&select USER_ID, BOOK_CODE
SQL&from TABLE_CLIENT_BOOK
SQL&order by tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE;
    USER_ID   BOOK_CODE
=========== ===========
          1         432
          1         568
          2         124
          2         567
          2         568
          3         123
          3         124
          3         568

                  8 rows found
```

Comment: And then maybe add GROUP BY tcb.USER_ID, tb.BOOK_CODE ORDER BY tcb.USER_ID to make it like the OP said.

Comment: @SQLDBA, what did I miss? I.e. why is a GROUP BY needed?

Comment: @SQLDBA . . . I don't see why a `GROUP BY` would be needed.

Comment: Because I actually ran the SQL in DB2, albeit v10.5, and it did not produce the result the OP was looking for...not until I added GROUP BY.  Copied the answer exactly.

Comment: @SQLDBA, yes, of course, user_id isn't unique in first table... So you get duplicates. Will edit! Thanks!!!